# .htaccess image to web page redirect of sorts

Tags: image, .htaccess, redirect, html

I think this can be done, though not sure, so I came here to find out from you experts. I researched extensively, but always get the opposite of what I want to do. I was wondering if someone types in the image file URL (on server side) into an address bar if that could be directed to its corresponding web page.

For example:

One types in yourdomain.com/wp-content/uploads/image-name.jpg and it's directed to yourdomain.com/print/image-name (w/o .jpg)

So instead of one just seeing the image in a window, they will see the image, it's information and how to purchase it on my brand web site.

If that is not possible or the file name doesn't match, can directly typed server side image file URLs redirect to my website galleries or home page? And where in .htaccess would this code be located? Above begin wordpress or not?

If above Begin WP, will that interfere with this code that already exists? If so how would I exactly write it?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.sitename.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: To clarify, my site being down has nothing to do with the help I received here. I upgraded my web host account and there was a glitch when they migrated it.

Answer (score 0):

Insert this rule just below `RewriteEngine On` line:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /wp-content/uploads/(.+?)\.jpg [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /print/%1? [L,R=302,NE]
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply anubhava! Unfortunately that didn't work. When I type in the image file url it shows just the image. Any other ideas?

Comment: Create `/wp-content/uploads/.htaccess` and place this rule there after `RewriteEngine On`

Comment: Thanks again! I created an .htaccess file in named folder. Should I copy what is in the public .htaccess and put it in this file, then add this code? When I put in just your code and nothing else, it still just shows the image. Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: Just one rule is needed in `/wp-content/uploads/.htaccess` shown in my answer. What URL are you entering in browser? Is it `http://domain.com/wp-content/uploads/image-name.jpg`?

Comment: Well something glitch and my site is down. I'm getting it worked on now. The answer to your question: https://www.domain.com/©ibc-images/image-name.jpg

Comment: that's actually an https with www

Comment: But your original URL is: `https://domain.com/wp-content/uploads/image-name.jpg`?

Comment: Yes that was the original one, but I have the new folder as my WP uploads folder. All my images no longer have wp-content/uploads/ they have ©ibc-images/ When my site is working, they all show up as they should. Perhaps what is causing your code not to work is I'm using WooCommerce. When an image is set up as a print for sale, the image url would be something like: `https://www.domain.com/print/print-name/image-name` So sorry I'm not very good at all this. At the moment, I am waiting for a zip backup to hit my server to see if I can get my site up working again